# VPN connection in both ways

Tags: sql, networking, vpn

I am not familiar with VPN, Just a quick question:

I have a VPN connection to a *remote server* from my local computer. I can ping the remote server and also connect to the SQL server in that machine from the local computer, but I cant ping back from the remote server to the local machine. Is that the case with a VPN connection?

Comment: What VPN solution, what configuration, etc? In some cases, this would be expected behavior, in others not.

Comment: CISCO AnyConnect VPN version 2.5.1025

Comment: Do you get replies to the ping from the local machine to remote?  Is the local machine behind NAT?

Comment: I can ping from the local machine to the remote machine. What is meant by NAT?

Comment: NAT commonly used to translate multiple local IP addresses to a single external IP address.  For example, the router connecting your home computer to the internet will NAT all the computers in your house to a single external IP address.  If your local computer has an external IP address you can connect directly to it from the outside (ie, remote machine), if you're behind NAT you cannot connect directly from the outside to your local machine; you need to set up some kind of forwarding first.  This may be your issue.

Comment: (It depends how the network is set up though.  Does the VPN terminate at a Cisco device, or on the server?  Do you get an additional IP on your local machine in the same range as the remote machine, or is it in a different range?)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the firewall configuration.  It makes sense to stop connections/lock down computers that are VPNing as they are not within your network.  If you setup your own VPN you could configure it how you saw fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can ping the server on the secured network, that means you can get packets back to your host when you initiate it. Maybe, it has to do something with NAT.

Also, see your routes. Is there a route on the gateway that might be affecting traffic in this direction although as you said you can ping SQL server, so, the chances of that happening are low.

Check if you can ping the IP provided by the gateway on the host from the gateway.